# On Click Embedded Macro

Tags: ms-access, macros

I have an Item on my switchboard which launches "View By SO"

This report has a record source of query "SO Search"

Which prompts the user to enter the SO.

Once entered it will display a list of IDs (this being the primary key) which have the SO of what you entered.

I have then added an on click embedded macro

[image: On Dbl Click Macro]

So once the ID is clicked it will open the form "View by SO" and filter it by ID however it doesnt it just prompts me to enter the SO again and once i enter the same SO it will then go to the form which is filtered down by the ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are very adept at performing certain functions, and they're very easy to work with.

This, however, probably isn't one of those times where a macro is the best solution.

I would consider doing this in VBA.  There are a number of ways to achieve this, but the best is probably to do the following:

1. Create a static query, called qryViewBySO.
2. Set the SO field in your query to have a Criteria of "[Enter SO]" (without the quotes)
3. Set the RecordSource of your report to "SELECT * FROM qryViewBySO"
4. Instead of having the On Click open the macro, have it open the report.

When the report opens, it will prompt the user **once** to enter the SO.  It will then filter by said SO.

This answer might not be 100% accurate because you've mentioned filtering by SO yet your macro seems to filter by ID, and you've referred to the resultant as both a Form and Report, so you'll have to adjust accordingly.